# sending mail takes too much time in java, how can i overcome that

Tags: java, email, spring-boot

In my spring-boot project, i have a function, to send email, there in the email, its taking too much time to send inside the transaction.

```
//service layer

    @Transaction
    function inviteUser() {
     // insert in invitation table
     // insert in invitation sub-table
     // sending  mail to user (30 seconds)
    }
```

its taking around 30 seconds in sending mail, how can i overcome that. is there any other specific way to do this kind of functionality.

Comment: Why send it inside a transaction?

Comment: You should separate your data access logic from tasks like sending email, a transaction should be closed as soon as possible once created.

Comment: @JerryChin Thanks for the comment, you have helped the novice programmer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spring-boot you can use @Async annotation,

```
@Transactional
    public void register() {
   //after success call that method
    emailService.sendWelcomeMail();
    }


    @Service
    @Configuration
    @EnableAsync
    public class EmailService {

        // for sending email
        @Async
        public void sendWelcomeMail(){}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Kayaman and @JerryChin commented, there is probably no need to send an email as part of a DB transaction:

//service layer

```
// Inject r/w transaction template.

// No @Transactional annotation
function inviteUser() {
    txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Object>() {
        public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus txStatus) {
          // insert in invitation table
          // insert in invitation sub-table
          ...
        }
    });
    // sending  mail to user
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In an application we often have to get data from various sources such as third party webservices, distributed data channels or even within our application microservices which are distributed accross network. Lets take a scenario where you need to fetch data from multiple sources and combine into single result and return to the caller. Eg. We have GetMyDataService which calls below services:

Service 1 ---> get data from webservices mywebservice.com (Response time 10 Secs , timeout 15 secs).

Service 2 ---> get data from some third party api, www.free.com/api/getData (Response time 5 secs, timeout 15 secs).

Service 3 ---> get data from one of your own microservice /myMicroservice/api/getData (Response time 1 secs, timeout 15 secs),

So in synchronous mode GetMyDataService will take atleast 10 + 5 + 1 = 16 secs even if the all three services are running properly. Lets say service 1 & 2 is down. Now the response time for GetMyDataService will be 15 + 15 +1 =31 seconds to get response. (Response includes only result fron service 3)

What if timeout was not configured??? The application would have hanged, waiting for response forever.

To overcome above situation there is rescuer "Hystrix" from Netflix. In this project we would demonstrate below solution:

The GetMyDataService will call all 3 services with timeout of 15 seconds. We will receive the whatever response we get in max 15 seconds or less.
On failure of any service or timeout we will have fallback with interrupting the thread which is waiting for service and return blank result.

### For detailed explaination on Hystrix check : https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use

```
@Service
public class MailService extends HystrixCommand<Boolean>{

protected MailService(){
    super(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey(MailService.class.getSimpleName()));

}



protected Boolean getFallback(){
    return new Boolean;
}

@Override
protected List<String> run() throws Exception {
     //Send Mail Here
}
}
```

and call it using by this

```
@Service
public class MyService {

@Autowired
MailService mailService;


public Boolean sendMail() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    Boolean isMailSend=new Boolean;
     Observable.merge(mailService.observe().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())).toBlocking().subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public void call(Boolean b) {
                     isMailSend = b;

                }
            });
     return isMailSend;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer looks more like an advertisement for Hystrix than a real answer. He hasn't indicated anywhere that he's using Hystrix, and that makes this a bad answer to a bad question.